# auto_increment_increment value for MySQL Group Replication on Single-Primary Mode

Tags: mysql, proxysql

We are setting up this servers stack:

- 1x ProxySQL Server
- 2x MySQL Servers

We are using MySQL Group Replication between the 2 MySQL servers on "Single-Primary" Mode.

The default value for auto_increment_increment with this config is 7.

It's safe to set "auto_increment_increment" to 1 when using Single-Primary Mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, when in single primary mode the auto_increment_increment value as no effect on value generation as the single primary is the only source of updates.